# S4 error: methods can be defined, but the generic function is implicit, and cannot be changed

Tags: r, r-package, r-s4

I'm creating the following method via S4

```
#' @name +
#' @title Expand outputs 
#' @description
#'
#' Operator outputs of function 'create' 
#'
#' @return expanded creation
#' @exportMethod +
#' @aliases +
#' @export
setGeneric('+', function(dt, ...) standardGeneric('+'))
setMethod('+', signature(dt = 'data.table'), function(dt, out) {
    return(create(dt, out))
})
```

I put the following into my R package. When I run `devtools::document()`, I run into the following problem:

```
Error in setGeneric("+", function(dt, ...) standardGeneric("+")) : 
  ‘+’ dispatches internally;  methods can be defined, but the generic function is implicit, and cannot be changed.
```

This appears to be a fatal error, and I cannot create documentation otherwise.

(1) What does this error mean? I'm unsure how I'm supposed to debug this.

(2) When creating an R package, what would be the correct way to work with this error? Should I create the documentation first with another name besides `+` and then change this afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a builtin function, the definition of the generic `+` cannot be changed, as the error message says. Much of R would break if you did redefine it this way.

`+` is defined to have two arguments, `e1` and `e2`. Using this framework, you can modify your example to be

```
setMethod('+', signature(e1 = 'data.table', e2='ANY'), function(dt, out) {
    return(create(dt, out))
})
```

One thing to note is that `e1` is always the first argument, even if argument names are used. so `"+"(e2=A,e1=B)` is equal to `A+B`, not `B+A`.