# S4 error: '+' dispatches internally; methods can be defined, but the generic function is implicit, and cannot be changed

Tags: r, r-s4

But getting this error

```
Error in setGeneric("+", function(x, y) standardGeneric("+")) : 
  '+' dispatches internally;  methods can be defined, but the generic function is implicit, and cannot be changed.
Execution halted
```

after running the below code

```
> setClass("string", representation(
+   data = "character"))
> 
> setGeneric("+", function(x, y) standardGeneric("+"))
setMethod("+", "string", "string", function(x, y) { 
  new("string", data = paste0(x@data, y@data)) })
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562252/s4-error-methods-can-be-defined-but-the-generic-function-is-implicit-and-cann?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much of S4 classes, but a quick help page shows that:

```
setClass("string", representation(data = "character"))
setGeneric("+.string", function(x, y) new("string", data = paste0(x@data, y@data)))

x <- new("string", data = "stack")
y <- new("string", data = "overflow")
x+y

An object of class "string"
Slot "data":
[1] "stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 1):

`"+"` already exists as a generic so you can't use `setGeneric("+"` I think (I don't master S4). Here is a way which works:

```r
setClass(
  "string",
  slots = c(data = "character")
)

setMethod(
  "+", 
  signature(e1 = "string", e2 = "string"), 
  function(e1, e2) {
    new("string", data = paste0(e1@data, e2@data))
  }
)

x <- new("string", data = "stack")
y <- new("string", data = "overflow")
x + y
```

Comment: This is correct --- the only other thing to note is that S4 methods for `+` and other internal generics are only dispatched for S4 objects (i.e. `isS4()` has to be `TRUE` for at least one of the arguments to `+`). You can't do something like `setOldClass` and then write S4 methods, because the objects in question won't be S4 so there won't be a check for S4 methods.